# EMV Kernel for CLess Interac card?

Tags: kernel, contactless-smartcard, emv

I am going through emv contactless process and i am not getting which kernel is used for interac card transactions? in emv cless books they mentioned about Visa, Mastercard, JCB, American express etc but there is no Interac card mentioned, i am working on it and new in this emv field.
please give details about it, also if you give some links regarding emv contact and contactless flow process explained with sample code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

KJ, 
the interac specification is proprietary. Even though it follows the EMV standard, you'll need to be Interac accredited to get access to the specification. I had access to it in a previous job, but I couldn't tell you how you get accredited. You'll then have to purchase an Interac Kernel (ex : from Ingenico, if you work with their terminals).

You may find helpful this [recording of a sample Interac Flash transaction](http://nicolas.riousset.com/category/software-methodologies/example-of-an-emv-dialog-for-an-interacflash-transaction/).

Comment: Thanks Nicolas for answer.. your site is good for emv beginners.

Answer (score 0):

I confirm. "recording of a sample Interac Flash transaction" is consistent with what you can get looking at your Interac cards and cards of your friends and family with the help of Android app is “NFC EMV Explorer” (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wwopenfare.readnfccard).

You can even explore with this app the virtual cards inside Google and Apple Pay. To my experience, nothing has changed. Interac does not follow any kernel. Moreover, there are no signs in the data flow that Interac supports Offline Data Authentication (a.k.a. DDA, CDA, fDDA) which is mandatory by EMV for offline transactions. Hence, it is risky to use Flash in Open Systems transit systems.